# Using Python Docx to remove blank lines

Tags: python, python-docx

I am using Python `docx` to remove blank lines from documents containing text and images. Using the `paragraph.clear()` and `paragraph.run.clear()` works to a point, but the outputted file still has blank lines which only have a paragraph mark shown in Word. Is there a way of searching directly for paragraph marks? Or is there a better way of clearing the lines?

```
# code snippet
for paragraphs in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraphs.text == "\n":
        paragraphs.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

Empty lines are not marked by "\n" but by empty string "".

Plus, `clear()` removes text but not the paragraph itself.

Try to test `len(paragraph.text)==0` for each paragraph.

Comment: `len(paragraph.text.strip()) == 0` would be one step more thorough, as it would also detect paragraphs that only contain whitespace.

Comment: Using `len(paragraph.text.strip()) == 0` unfortunately strips out the images in conjunction with  `clear()`, `len(paragraph.text)==0` picks it up. What  should I use to remove the paragraph itself?

Answer (score 1):

This removed all the empty lines for me in my document file

```
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
   if len(paragraph.text) == 0:
      p = paragraph._element
      p.getparent().remove(p)
      p._p = p._element = None
```

Comment: Could you maybe add some explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using `len(paragraph.text)==1` helps as opposed to using `len(paragraph.text)==0` as new line is also a character.
I just wanted to copy the lines except the blank lines to a new document so it gave  me the output.
When I used `paragraph.text=paragraph.strip('\n')` the font style,bold,underlined and italic were removed.So checking the length of each paragraph and clearing that paragraph does the trick.